# Invoke function after loading my custom.bzl

Tags: bazel

Let's suppose I have custom.bzl with only one function (def foo():).
I load custom.bzl from 2 BUILD files and invoke 'manually' function foo().
According to domain model, I know that each loading of custom.bzl I should do only one thing: invoke foo().
So, here's a question: is there any way to automatically invoke one particular function every time when the bzl-file been loaded into BUILD-file?

Comment: For a start, this sounds like an XY problem, so you may get better answers describing what you want to achieve with it! That said, you may be able to simply call the function.

Comment: Hello Ulrich,
For now I'm calling one function from BUILD like this:
load("path-to/custom.bzl", "foo")
foo()
======
I want something like this:
load_enchanced("path-to/custom.bzl", "foo") # when function foo() invoked under the hood.

Comment: Can't you put the call into custom.bzl?

Comment: Sure I can. BUT, "Error in config_setting: The native module can be accessed only from a BUILD thread. Wrap the function in a macro and call it from a BUILD file
".

Comment: are you doing `native.config_setting(...)` in a BUILD file? You can do just `config_setting(...)` in a BUILD file.